# Moodle - API for user registration

Tags: api, magento, moodle

I am integrating Magento and Moodle. Does moodle provides APIs to register users, assign user groups, create/edit/delete courses etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a web services api - http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/How_to_create_and_enable_a_web_service

In summary:

1. Enable the protocol - go to site admin -> plugins -> web services -> manage protocols and select the protocol required, eg REST.
2. On the same page check Web services documentation and save changes.
3. Read through the API documentation at site admin -> plugins -> web services -> api documentation - to find the functions required.
4. Create an external service and add the required functions for user registration, create courses etc. site admin -> plugins -> web services -> external service
5. Then create a token to access the service site admin -> plugins -> web services -> manage tokens

Comment: @Russell England, Which function need to select for User Registration? core_user_create_users, moodle_user_create_users or anything else