# Moodle: How to enable/configure registration through webservice

Tags: web-services, api, moodle, user-registration

I am totally new to moodle. Now exploring it to build a LMS. Here I need to implement core registration through API, so that user email verification works properly.There is a default API function to create core and moodle use. Does any of those types refer to registration? If no, is there any way to do user registration through API.

I have found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378790/moodle-api-for-user-registration) with accepted answer, where the API function is not mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I'm not convinced I understand the question correctly, I'll give it a try...

It's certainly possible to create new users in Moodle through API calls (hopefully that's what you call registration). You can do it through PHP using function user_create_user() (defined in user/lib.php) and you can do it through a web service, with a call to core_user_create_users.

Either way, I think it completely bypasses email verification, meaning that Moodle will not check whether the provided email address is valid or not. If you want a "syntax check", you can call validate_email() (in weblib.php).  There's also send_confirmation_email() (in moodlelib.php) that will send the confirmation email, with link. You would need to do it manually (and set confirmed to false, when creating the user, to prevent anyone from logging in before having confirmed their email address).

(EDIT: looking the linked question..) To use a webservice and trigger the email validation, I would create a new webservice (using a local plugin) to receive the "new user request" and hook into the auth/email plugin. Actually, you might just want to add a webservice into auth/email...!

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: thanks @scyrma, I have already created users using that API. But email verification is the main issue now. I will try to use your thought and let you know...

Comment: @Sadat, I'm curious to know how this went, since I'm working on something similar these days... Any news?

Comment: At last I have planned to create user through Moodle API, since there is no API for registration.

Comment: Hello @Sadat were you able to finally create users using the Moodle API?